# Selenium wont execute onChange in select element, when chosing option

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

The problem is that, code below won't execute onChange, **though the text in mentioned Select actually changes**. There is a script that makes another 5 input elements visible if certain option was selected. Therefore input elements are invisible and cannot be tested.

Here is my java code:

```
text = "option1";
WebElement comboBoxElement = webDriver.findElement(By.id(id));
new Actions(getWebDriver()).moveToElement(comboBoxElement).perform();
Select selectElement = new Select(comboBoxElement);
if (value != null) {
    selectElement.selectByValue(value);
}
else if (text != null) {
    selectElement.selectByVisibleText(text);
}
```

Comment: Please take a minute to properly format/indent your code and remove the random text inside. You seem to be missing key parts of the code because you haven't defined `value` or `text`. Provided code samples should be runnable. Add a link to the page to your question or at least provide some of the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you are unable to see fields even after an element was selected from the dropdown; so you can execute JS function manually which is to be called during onChange:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("yourFunction();");
```